# SQL - Transformar diferentes valores de uma Coluna em várias colunas com count em cada uma delas

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

A minha dúvida é quanto separar diferentes valores de uma coluna em várias colunas e dar um count em cada item de acordo com o nome no postgres, segue exemplo abaixo

Como está:

```
--TIPO O.S.--Count----Nome

     1009 ||   1   || Lucas    
     1008 ||   2   || Lucas    
     1008 ||   2   || Juliana  
     1007 ||   2   || Juliana  
     1007 ||   2   || Lucas
     1008 ||   2   || Vanessa 
     1007 ||   3   || Vanessa 

SQL: select os.tipo_os,count(os.tipo_os), pe.nome_usuario 
from table_os as os, table_pessoas as pe 
where os.codigo_usuario = pe.codpessoa
group by os.tipo_os, pe.nome_usuario
```

Como é pra Ficar:

```
--1009----1008----1007----Nome

   1   ||   2  ||   2  || Lucas    
       ||   2  ||   2  || Juliana     
       ||   2  ||   3  || Vanessa
```

Comment: Você quer uma `Pivot Table`, porém no postgresql você tem que informar quais seriam as colunas, ele não consegue isso de forma dinâmica. Veja: http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function

Comment: Mesmo sendo o entendimento um pouco mais complicado que o resultado apresentado pelo Bruno, me parece que também funciona Rovann, porém não cheguei a testar !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fica aqui uma possível solução:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN OS.TIPO_OS = '1009' THEN OS.TIPO_OS END) AS '1009',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN OS.TIPO_OS = '1008' THEN OS.TIPO_OS END) AS '1008',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN OS.TIPO_OS = '1007' THEN OS.TIPO_OS END) AS '1007',
       PE.nome_usuario AS Nome
  FROM table_os AS OS
 INNER JOIN table_pessoas AS PE
    ON OS.codigo_usuario = PE.codpessoa
 GROUP BY PE.nome_usuario
```

Comment: Deu certo bruno, não conhecia esse tipo de condição, ainda mais utilizado dentro do count, porém é totalmente funcional !!